# Numbering MySQL Result Row

Tags: sql, mysql, resultset

i have a **mysql result set** like bellow

```
id        name
---------------------
1         abc
1         abc
2         xyz
2         xyz
3         pqr
```

now i need to **modify the result set** so that it would be like as follows:

```
id        name
---------------------
1         abc-1
1         abc-2
2         xyz-1
2         xyz-2
3         pqr
```

the summarization is i need to **numbering the name column** from result set and the numbering will **only apply on the rows which have more than one value** in the result set.

so what will be the **MySQL *SELECT* Query**?

Comment: What all have you tried?

Comment: do you need to actually modify the data on the table or just the results of the query. Either way, it would help to see your actual table structure and/or the query you are already using to select the data already.

Comment: this is a query result. i don't need to modify the data. i only need the SELECT query,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might work but there's probably a better way that i can't think of right now

```
set @i = 0;

select
 f.id,
 @i:=@i+1 as i,
 case 
  when c.counter <= 1 then f.name 
  else concat(f.name,'-',(@i % c.counter) +1)
 end as name
from
 foo f
join (select id, count(*) as counter from foo group by id) c on c.id = f.id
order by
 f.id,name;
```

EDIT: as stated in comments above, better to do this at the app level vs. db

Comment: case can be replaced with if, variable can be declared as (select @i:=0) i in FROM clause

Comment: it's really helpful but there is a left join in my query that made the result set complicated. don't get the desired result yet. :(

Answer (score 2):

I see 3 possible ways to resolve this:

1. Update all values in DB once, and then check on each insert/update/delete, whether numbering has to be updated. As far as I know, this can be done either in program, which uses database, or with triggers
2. Generate numbering with SQL query - this will require join table with itself on id, group results and count amount of rows with similar id. This will look in the following way:
   `select t1.id, t1.name, count(t2.id) from t1, t2 where t1.id = t2.id group by t2.id`
   (BTW, this query may take O(N^2) time, which is long for large table)
   Then you'll have to analyze third column and get final result.
3. Do post-processing of result in your program by means of programming language. This looks like the most easy and efficient solution.

Comment: +1 for option 3 -- this doesn't seem like something that would be worthwhile doing in SQL; just have a loop in your calling program which has a counter variable that is incremented if ID is the same and resets when the ID field changes.